# How can I save scan data(topic) in npy file?

Tags: python, linux, numpy, save, ros

I'm newbie in ros

I'm trying to save LiDAR Laserscan data to npy file to check my test code without launching ros.

The ideal form i wanna save is numpy array file which contains every information in each Laserscan topic data such as header(stamp, seq), angle data(angle_min, --), ranges.

I hope I can use this data at the my test code. It looks like

```
buffer = np.load('scan_save.npy', allow_pickle = True)

buffer[0] = prev_scan

for scan in buffer[1:]:

    scan.header.stamp - prev_scan.stamp = dt
    function(scan.ranges)
...
```

I have no idea how to save all of scan data together not only 'ranges' but 'header, angle_min, time_increment'

Also, I want append each scan data every time scan subscriber get the scan data

Only thing I can do is

```
scandata = msg.ranges # msg is Laserscan
np.save("~/scan_save", scandata)
```

Comment: I searched rosbag. But It looks like I have to extract every information from the save file again. Tell me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! There should be a minimum content in one question: Input sample (if needed), expected output sample (is needed), what you try, what you research... What did you try?

Comment: Thanks @DavidGarcíaBodego I've solved my problem :) I can not define my sample because I haven't decided to do with this code haha. I just wanted to check several ros function!

Answer (score 2):

I solved my qustion! here is my code :)

By dong this, I could save all of topic as numpy array

```
self.scan_data = np.array([]) # define it at __init__

'''at the scan callbalck function'''
buffer = msg # Laserscan msg from subscriber
self.scan_data = np.array(buffer)
self.save_scan = np.append(self.save_scan, scan_data)
np.save("~/record/scan", self.save_scan)
```